# How to add lines dynamically to a listview?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listview

I am a beginner in Android Java programming, and I have a problem with the creation of a listview.

I want to dynamically add lines in each listview item.

My data comes from the following JSON:

```
{
   "online":"1",
   "success":1,
   "data":[
      {
         "zi":"1",
         "zn":"Zone 1",
         "vannes":[
            {
               "vn":"Value 01",
               "ve":"0",
               "st":"1",
               "es":"1",
               "eo":"0"
            },
            {
               "vn":"Value 02",
               "ve":"0",
               "st":"3",
               "es":"0",
               "eo":"0"
            },
            {
               "vn":"Value 03",
               "ve":"1",
               "st":"3",
               "es":"0",
               "eo":"0"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "zi":"2",
         "zn":"Zone 2",
         "vannes":[
            {
               "vn":"Value 01",
               "ve":"0",
               "st":"1",
               "es":"1",
               "eo":"0"
            },
            {
               "vn":"Value 03",
               "ve":"1",
               "st":"3",
               "es":"0",
               "eo":"0"
            },
            {
               "vn":"Value A",
               "ve":"0",
               "st":"3",
               "es":"0",
               "eo":"0"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "zi":"3",
         "zn":"Zone 3",
         "vannes":[
            {
               "vn":"Value 01",
               "ve":"0",
               "st":"1",
               "es":"1",
               "eo":"0"
            },
            {
               "vn":"Value B",
               "ve":"1",
               "st":"3",
               "es":"0",
               "eo":"0"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "zi":"4",
         "zn":"Zone 4",
         "vannes":[
            {
               "vn":"Value B",
               "ve":"1",
               "st":"3",
               "es":"0",
               "eo":"0"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "zi":"6",
         "zn":"Zone A",
         "vannes":[
            {
               "vn":"Value 01",
               "ve":"0",
               "st":"1",
               "es":"1",
               "eo":"0"
            },
            {
               "vn":"Value 03",
               "ve":"1",
               "st":"3",
               "es":"0",
               "eo":"0"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "zi":"7",
         "zn":"Zone B",
         "vannes":[
            {
               "vn":"Value A",
               "ve":"0",
               "st":"3",
               "es":"0",
               "eo":"0"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "zi":"5",
         "zn":"Zone Test",
         "vannes":[
            {
               "vn":"Value 02",
               "ve":"0",
               "st":"3",
               "es":"0",
               "eo":"0"
            },
            {
               "vn":"Value 03",
               "ve":"1",
               "st":"3",
               "es":"0",
               "eo":"0"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

My Java code is as follows. **It is probably not very well structured, nor clean, but I am a beginner ....please be indulgent :-) I only ask to learn to improve**

```
zones = jsonObject.getJSONArray(KEY_DATA);
```

.
    for (int i = 0; i < zones.length(); i++) {

```
    HashMap < String, String > map = new HashMap < > ();
    JSONObject zone = zones.getJSONObject(i);
    final Integer zi = zone.getInt(KEY_ZONE_ID);
    final String zoneName = zone.getString(KEY_ZONE_NAME);

    map.put(KEY_ZONE_ID, zi.toString());
    map.put(KEY_ZONE_NAME, zoneName.toString());

    JSONObject vannes = zones.getJSONObject(i);

    for (int j = 0; j < vannes.length(); j++) {

        JSONArray vannedetail = vannes.getJSONArray(KEY_DATA_VANNES);
        for (int k = 0; k < vannedetail.length(); k++) {
            JSONObject vv = vannedetail.getJSONObject(k);
            final String vanneName = vv.getString(KEY_VANNE_NAME);
            map.put(KEY_VANNE_NAME, vanneName.toString());

        }

    }

    zoneList.add(map);
}
```

Then this way I set my list adapter:

```
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(

        VanneListingActivity.this, zoneList,
        R.layout.list_item,

        new String[] {
                KEY_ZONE_NAME,
                KEY_VANNE_NAME,
        },
        new int[] {
                R.id.zoneName,
                R.id.vanneName,
        });

zoneListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**UPDATE :** ListView XML :

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/zoneList"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:paddingTop="4dp"
    android:dividerHeight="6dp"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
</ListView>
```

and list_item.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/list_background"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="10dp">

<!--hidden values -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/zi"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/stationEtat"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/zoneName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="Nom de la Zone"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:textColor="#ff0000"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/vanneName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/zoneName"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:text="Nom de la vanne"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/vanneEtat"
    android:layout_width = "match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/zoneName"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:paddingTop="18dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textColor="#ea00ff"/>
```

**It works, I get the following result:** *(The purple text "ListView" and for other information that I wish to display)*

Here is the result :

[Obtained result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlwLn.jpg)

I obviously get the last element in the loop ...

But that's not what I want, Here is the desired result. The number of lines per object depends on my JSON file.

Here is a quick edit to explain the result I'm looking for.

[Expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/272ci.jpg)

I hope I'm clear enough in the description of my problem. After much research on the internet, I guess I need to dynamically create a listview (without XML?) But I do not really know how to do this.

I hope I have provided enough elements for you to help me.

I am facing problem... all the helpers will be welcome  :-s

Sorry for my bad english

Comment: post your `ListView` item `xml`

Comment: just updated with the ListView xml

Comment: i mean your `list_item.xml`

Comment: Ok, done. The layout is weird because I found a workaround very ugly for my problem ... I made a concatenation of Strings at each loop by adding "\n" .... It works but it's horrible ...  any help to improve is welcome

Comment: Your data structure of response seems nested array then why didn't you use section recyclerview there is many libraries available checkout this https://gist.github.com/gabrielemariotti/4c189fb1124df4556058

Comment: it seems to be a very good solution to my problem ... I will try but I do not know if I will get there with my beginner level ...:(

Answer (score -1):

[refer this example](https://www.journaldev.com/10416/android-listview-with-custom-adapter-example-tutorial&hl=en-IN)

Its nicely explained and meeting all ur requirements..if u will still having the issue..then let me know..
Will happy to help you.
Happy coding!

Comment: Thank you for your answer

I have already seen this link and downloaded the sample source code, but I do not understand how to add lines in each listview element.

For example :

Line 1: Kitkat
Line 2: Android 4.4

and I need to be able to add lines (4 ... 5 etc) dynamically depending on the contents of the JSON.

This is where I have a problem ... I do not know the content of the JSON in advance. Sometimes there will be two lines, sometimes five ...

My problem is not adding elements in the listview, but adding lines to each element according to the JSON.

Comment: Just put the line with view like this in ur arapter view layout at the end..
<View android:background="#ffffff" android:layout_width = "match_parent" android:layout_height="1dp"/>

Comment: I see.. but  I;m not sure it will work  because each loop, I Write the same variable. For example::  JSONArray vannedetail = vannes.getJSONArray(KEY_DATA_VANNES); for (int k = 0; k &amp;amp;lt; vannedetail.length(); k++) { JSONObject vv = vannedetail.getJSONObject(k); final String vanneName = vv.getString(KEY_VANNE_NAME); map.put(KEY_VANNE_NAME, vanneName.toString())

I really dont know how to do it ... but Im pretty sure there is an easy solution...